# why numpy loadtxt does not work with "with" while load works

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, load, enter

```
np.__version__
Out[307]: '1.20.1'
```

np.loadtxt throws **enter** error

```
with np.loadtxt("textfile.txt",delimiter=",") as data1:
     ...:     print ("Hello")
     ...: 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-300-05181e15f7ec> in <module>
----> 1 with np.loadtxt("textfile.txt",delimiter=",") as data1:
      2     print ("Hello")

AttributeError: __enter__
```

same class i.e np does not throw **enter** error with load .
i wonder how **enter** and **exit** are bound to a class

```
with np.load("new.txt.npz") as data:
     ...:     print (data["a"])
     ...: 
     ...: 
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is taken from the `load` docs that state

```
If the file is a .npz file, the returned value supports the context 
manager protocol in a similar fashion to the open function:
```

and

```
For .npz files, the returned instance of NpzFile class must be closed to 
avoid leaking file descriptors.
```

Note the focus on `returned value`.  It's not `numpy` or `np.load` that works in the `with` context, it's the object returned by the call that does so.

`np.load` of a `.npy` file, or `np.loadtxt` returns a numpy array.  There's nothing that needs closing.  When given a file name, those calls open the file for reading, and then close it before exiting.

Look at `numpy.lib.npyio.py` for code.  The class `NpzFile` has `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods.